# Update SQL Server table from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the below code to take the active cell and update a table in SQL Server.

```
Sub UpdateTable()
Dim rngName As Range
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=MyServer; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=Mydb;" & _
            "User ID=User;" & _
            "Password=Pwd;" & _
            "Trusted_Connection=No"
Set rngName = ActiveCell
'Debug.Print (rngName)
 Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
cnn.Open cnnstr
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
uSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET FieldNameX = 1 WHERE FieldNameY = '" & rngName & "' "
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open uSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

When stepping through the code, it run time errors on the line rs.close, says `Operation is not allowed when the object is closed` I've set and opened the record set in the code so why would it be closed?

What would I need to do to correct the issue and let the active cell populate the query and update the table in SQL Server?

Comment: can you confirm that the recordset `rs` is successfully opened? Try `?rs.recordcount` in the Immediate Window (use CTRL_G). If the error is happening on the line 'rs.Open' then the conenction is probably not open.

Comment: Where should I put the line rs.recordcount? I placed it after my line rs.open, and it run time errors with Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: Your update SQL doesn't return any records, so you'd expect the recordset to be empty.  For updates you're much better off using the `Connection.Execute` approach - there is a parameter `RecordsAffected` you can use to determine how many rows were affected by your update.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675023(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why do you say my Update SQL doesn't return any records, when I do Debug.Print(uSQL) in the Immediate window it posts the SQL, I've tested this in SSMS and it will update the records. There will always just be one record to update and that would be the active cell in excel. I import the data from SQL Server and the Update query marks that records as downloaded from the table.

Comment: Your update doesn't **return** any records: all it does is *update* the table.  That doesn't cause any records to be *selected* and populate your recordset.

Comment: how embarrassing that I missed that !

Answer (score 6):

This below is the code I used to be able to update the table in SQL Server, this works just how I wanted. It takes the activecell and updates.

```
Sub UpdateTable()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim uSQL As String
Dim rngName As Range
Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=MyServer; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=Mydb;" & _
            "User ID=User;" & _
            "Password=Pwd;" & _
            "Trusted_Connection=No"
    Set rngName = ActiveCell
cnn.Open cnnstr
uSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET FieldNameX = 1 WHERE FieldNameY= '" & rngName & "' "
'Debug.Print (uSQL)
cnn.Execute uSQL
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```